# Jquery swipe to refresh mobile web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to refresh a mobile web page on-swipe. The html code is very basic, and just need the necessary jquery/javascript to get the swipe to reload the current page.

Here is the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/yKpLJ/1/  I am pulling in jquery and jquery ui as well, but don't know how to move forward.

```
    <div id="fact-footer">
        <ul>
            <li class="share facebook">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=&p[images][0]=&p[title]=&p[summary]=" target="_blank" title="">Share It</a>
            </li>
            <li class="share twitter">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=" target="_blank" title="">Tweet It</a>
            </li>
            <li class="refresh">
                <a href="." title="Fact">Refresh Fact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="" target="_blank" title="">Logo</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see what you have tried? This is not a give me the codes type of website, you must show us that you have attempted to make this work on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out HammerJS http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Include the script on your page and then do something like this:

```
var element = $('body');

Hammer(element).on("swipeleft", function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I want to vote it up, but I don't have enough creds :(

Comment: Great, I'm glad you go it working :) If it solved your problem, then you should be able to mark this as the correct answer - please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work